# Webview white screen problem only in phone screen

Tags: android, webview

The webview display in the phone is white, but if I use `webview.draw()` to draw a bitmap as a screenshot, the content in webview will show. Also, I can see content in chrome webview debug tools

This Phenomenon comes out less than 5% in all webview articles, I can use some function to fix this but I still can't detect white screen in webview

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or give me some useful methods to debug this?
Or who knows any method to capture picture from webview to detect white screen?

Here is my webview settings:

```
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webSettings.builtInZoomControls = true
    webSettings.displayZoomControls = false
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true                                         
    webSettings.useWideViewPort = true
    webSettings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    webSettings.textZoom = 100
    webSettings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true)
    webSettings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
```

Comment: Do you use HTTPS (instead of HTTP ) on the url ?

Comment: Close hardwareAccelerated will fix it, but it's very lagging when sliding

Comment: The url is HTTPS, this url is a html template, when load finish, I use js code to load my content  @LahEzcen